# How to bring user control front of another one when I click on it

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have 4 User controls in one window >> 
All what I want to do is that to bring any one of them front of all of them when I click on it.

Comment: Why not just use .Visible? Set the others to False and the one you want at the front to True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put all of your elements in canvas like that

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,131,0,150" Width="153">
        <Rectangle x:Name="E1" Canvas.ZIndex="98" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="100" Canvas.Left="53" Canvas.Top="60" MouseDown="E1_MouseDown"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="E2" Canvas.ZIndex="99" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Width="88" Height="134" MouseDown="E2_MouseDown"/>
    </Canvas>
```

Then you have to add some code in the `MouseDown` Event

P.S >> I make an example of just two elements `E1` and `E2`

```
    private void E1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        int zOrder = Canvas.GetZIndex(E2)+1;
        Canvas.SetZIndex(E1,zOrder);

    }

    private void E2_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        int zOrder = Canvas.GetZIndex(E1)+1;
        Canvas.SetZIndex(E2,zOrder);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

youcan use  [`Panel.SetZIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.PANEL.SETZINDEX%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) to give your control in front

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Panel.ZIndex` Property. More can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/06/13/controlling-zorder-using-the-zindex-property.aspx)

Sample

```
<Canvas Background="Ivory"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

  <Canvas>
    <Rectangle Height="60" Width="60" Fill="Gold"/>
    <Rectangle Height="50" Width="70" Fill="Coral"/>
    <Rectangle Height="40" Width="80" Fill="Teal"/>
    <Rectangle Height="30" Width="90" Fill="Black"/>
  </Canvas>

  <Canvas Canvas.Left="120">
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="99" Height="60" Width="60" Fill="Gold"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="98" Height="50" Width="70" Fill="Coral"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="97" Height="40" Width="80" Fill="Teal"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="96" Height="30" Width="90" Fill="Black"/>
  </Canvas>

</Canvas>
```

Notice how the second set of Rectangle objects is layered in reverse z-order from the first set of Rectangle objects:

[image]

Default and explicit Z-order

Comment: How can I do this with c#